# CodeIgniter return joined table query result with one object

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i am trying to join table in this way

```
 $this->db->select("users.id,users.name,users.lastname,users.bio,rating.Rating"); 
            $this->db->where('users.id', $id);

            $this->db->join('video', 'video.user_id = users.id');
             $this->db->join('rating', 'rating.IDvideo = video.ID');

            $results = array();
            $results['info'] = $this->db->get('users')->result();
```

I get results

```
array (size=1)
  'info' => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[26]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'Vladimir' (length=8)
          public 'lastname' => string 'Stus' (length=4)
          public 'bio' => string 'Dragi prijatelji, po zanimanju sam PHP programer. Trenutno radim u jednoj poznatoj kompaniji koja se bavi pre svega obrazovanjem i razvojem aplkacija kojima se sti?u nova IT znanja. U slobodno vreme pravim tutorijale o web programiranju, koje možete na?i ' (length=256)
          public 'Rating' => string '3.5' (length=3)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[27]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'Vladimir' (length=8)
          public 'lastname' => string 'Stus' (length=4)
          public 'bio' => string 'Dragi prijatelji, po zanimanju sam PHP programer. Trenutno radim u jednoj poznatoj kompaniji koja se bavi pre svega obrazovanjem i razvojem aplkacija kojima se sti?u nova IT znanja. U slobodno vreme pravim tutorijale o web programiranju, koje možete na?i ' (length=256)
          public 'Rating' => string '4.7' (length=3)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[28]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'Vladimir' (length=8)
          public 'lastname' => string 'Stus' (length=4)
          public 'bio' => string 'Dragi prijatelji, po zanimanju sam PHP programer. Trenutno radim u jednoj poznatoj kompaniji koja se bavi pre svega obrazovanjem i razvojem aplkacija kojima se sti?u nova IT znanja. U slobodno vreme pravim tutorijale o web programiranju, koje možete na?i ' (length=256)
          public 'Rating' => string '1.6' (length=3)
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[29]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'Vladimir' (length=8)
          public 'lastname' => string 'Stus' (length=4)
          public 'bio' => string 'Dragi prijatelji, po zanimanju sam PHP programer. Trenutno radim u jednoj poznatoj kompaniji koja se bavi pre svega obrazovanjem i razvojem aplkacija kojima se sti?u nova IT znanja. U slobodno vreme pravim tutorijale o web programiranju, koje možete na?i ' (length=256)
          public 'Rating' => string '2.6' (length=3)
      4 => 
        object(stdClass)[30]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'Vladimir' (length=8)
          public 'lastname' => string 'Stus' (length=4)
          public 'bio' => string 'Dragi prijatelji, po zanimanju sam PHP programer. Trenutno radim u jednoj poznatoj kompaniji koja se bavi pre svega obrazovanjem i razvojem aplkacija kojima se sti?u nova IT znanja. U slobodno vreme pravim tutorijale o web programiranju, koje možete na?i ' (length=256)
          public 'Rating' => string '3.4' (length=3)
      5 => 
        object(stdClass)[31]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'Vladimir' (length=8)
          public 'lastname' => string 'Stus' (length=4)
          public 'bio' => string 'Dragi prijatelji, po zanimanju sam PHP programer. Trenutno radim u jednoj poznatoj kompaniji koja se bavi pre svega obrazovanjem i razvojem aplkacija kojima se sti?u nova IT znanja. U slobodno vreme pravim tutorijale o web programiranju, koje možete na?i ' (length=256)
```

is it possible with join to get results with one object something like this

```
array (size=1)
  'info' => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[26]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'Vladimir' (length=8)
          public 'lastname' => string 'Stus' (length=4)
          public 'bio' => string 'Dragi prijatelji, po zanimanju sam PHP programer. Trenutno radim u jednoj poznatoj kompaniji koja se bavi pre svega obrazovanjem i razvojem aplkacija kojima se sti?u nova IT znanja. U slobodno vreme pravim tutorijale o web programiranju, koje možete na?i ' (length=256)
          public 'Rating' => string '3.5' (length=3)
          public 'Rating' => string '1.5' (length=3)
          public 'Rating' => string '2.5' (length=3)public 'Rating' => string '3.5' (length=3)
```

I mean rating is from one user, could i get all rating in one object not many objects or sum of user ratings? Help is needed i one to solve this problem with MYSQL

Comment: As far as I'm aware this isn't easily done with SQL. However, you could use PHP to transform the data into the structure you want, where 'Rating' is an array of ratings for one user.

Comment: you suggest making mulyple queries?

Comment: Your desired result doesn't make sense. You can't have multiple properties with the same name `Rating`. What you should do is loop over the results and collect all the ratings for the same user ID into an array.

Comment: I think that the data you have is good data. If you really want it to look more like what you've shown at the bottom, the structure would be more like `object( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Vladimir', 'lastname' => 'Stus', 'bio' => 'blah', 'Ratings' => array())`

Comment: You could also use `GROUP_CONCAT(rating.Rating)` to collect all the ratings in a comma-separated string, then use `explode(',', $results->info[$i]->Rating)`

Comment: @Barmar's solution is probably the easiest to implement